# Can't configure logging for executable jar

Tags: java, maven, logging, netbeans, jar

This is similar to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370989/how-to-configure-logging-when-running-a-jar), although I already put the `logging.properties` in the executable jar and doesn't work.

I have a class (ReportGenerator) that has the following:

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReportGenerator.class.getName());
 logger.log(Level.INFO, "LOG THIS");
```

I'm using Netbeans so I put the `logging.properties` file in the path `src/main/resources`. It has this (among other things):

```
# default file output is in user's home directory.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /my/folder/reports.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
com.mypackage.ReportGenerator.level = ALL
```

The jar is generated using Maven, when decompressed I can see that the `logging.properties` is in the main folder of the jar. Along with the folder `com` where my class is.

```
-com
  -mypackage
      -ReportGenerator
logging.properties
...other things
```

When I run from console:

```
java - jar MyReportsJar.jar
```

It shows me the logs through the console. I want to log it to the file I set in the `logging.properties.`

What am I doing wrong?
How do I do it without setting the JVM `java.util.logging.config.file` param?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After dealing a few days against this and reading many resources on the Internet I came up with this solution:

I have to change the logging properties of the [LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) in the program. I can use the `logging.properties` file packaged in the `.jar` like this:

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ReportGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));
```

And then I can do the same as before to get the logger and log:

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReportGenerator.class.getName());
 logger.log(Level.INFO, "LOG THIS");
```

But I found very useful that you can specify another `logging.properties` file on runtime so my final code is this:

```
        String logFile = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file");
        if(logFile == null){
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ReportGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));
        }                
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReportGenerator.class.getName());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "LOG THIS");
```

That way, if I execute the jar as this:

```
java -jar MyReportsJar.jar
```

It uses the internal `logging.properties` file.

But if I execute:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=<external-logging.properties> -jar MyReportsJar.jar
```

it uses the external `logging.properties` file.