# how come my log4j messages do not appear in log file?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I've created `log4j.properties` file and put it under `/src/main/resources/`, the content of this file is:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out
# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I would like to see the logs in file `log.out`, but when I run the app with command:

```
java -jar myapp.jar -Dlog4j.debug
```

the file is not created.

This is - as requested in comments - how I use it in code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and later:

```
LOG.debug("some message");

LOG.error("some other msg", error);
```

Comment: Hi. can you please show your code with log line?

Comment: @Mara I've added it to the original question,thanks for suggesting it

Comment: Where is the log file specified in the log4j.properties file?

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni I didn't create it, I thought it will be created automatically during app run? Do I have to create it manually? If so - where?

Comment: I have just worked on it yesterday

Comment: you do not need to create log output file by hand. after app run it should be created automatically

Comment: I would say problem is not in your code but in way you run the jar. Here there is already answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370989/how-to-configure-logging-when-running-a-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find implementation below:

> `log4j.properties`

under `

> src/main/resources

`

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/demo/logs/myapp/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Along with this i also have the `Logger` imported in the `class`.

```
package org.nbk.demo;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class ServerStartup {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServerStartup.class);
    public void onApplicationEvent() {
            logger.info("Information Messages");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me if that works with `logger.debug` and `logger.error`? And if not, how should we modify it so it contains all of the necessary log entries?

Comment: in the log4j.properties, you change from `INFO` to `DEBUG`. In the code change from `logger.info` to `logger.debug`

Comment: can I use `DEBUG`, `ERROR` and `INFO` simultaneously?

Comment: `TRACE` is the lowest level of logging, it will print you all the logs including `TRACE` to`FATAL`, if you specify in `log4j`. But in production, i suggest you to use the `ERROR` logs, as the file will be filled very fast, Hence the posibility of application being slow is also more as it has to write to the log file always.

Comment: For more you can see the below link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_quick_guide.htm