# java.util.logging breaks on wsl with spaces in paths

Tags: java, whitespace, windows-subsystem-for-linux, java.util.logging

I have a small Java project setup with the 3 files `Foo.java`, `logging.properties` and `build.gradle` as below.

In the `Foo.java`, I run the below

```java
package foo;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Foo {

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        var file = Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logging.properties").getFile();
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", file);
        var l = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());
        l.info("HOLA!");
    }
}
```

and the corresponding properties file is simply

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

The gradle file is simple enough.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

they are structured like below

```
foo/
├─ src/
│  ├─ java/
│  │  ├─ main/
│  │  │  ├─ foo/
│  │  │  │  ├─ Foo.java
│  ├─ resources/
│  │  ├─ logging.properties
├─ build.gradle
```

to run the code, I write

```
gradle build
java -cp build/classes/java/main/:build/resources/main/ foo.Foo
```

Now to my problem: if I locate `root` in `/mnt/c/Users/Ludvig/Desktop/logtest/root`, all works well. If I change the path be `/mnt/c/Users/Ludvig/Desktop/log test/root` I get no log output. Notice that it fails silently! So the program runs, but the logging fails. What to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure logging when running a JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370989/how-to-configure-logging-when-running-a-jar)

Comment: unfortunately not. it is only concerned with JARs. not file system paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert URL to File by doing:

```
package foo;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.File;

public class Foo {

    public static void  main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var file = new File(Foo.class.getResource("logging.properties").toURI());
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", file.getCanonicalPath());
        var l = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());
        l.info("HOLA!");
    }
}
```

You don't have to convert the URL to a file.  The `LogManager` supports `InputStream` objects as long as your code explicitly reconfigures the loggers before any other code is run.

```
package foo;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private static final Logger logger;
    static {
        try (InputStream in = Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties")) {
           //LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(in); //JDK 8
           LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(in, (k) -> ((o, n) -> n)); //JDK 9+
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ioe);
        }
     logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());
}

public class Foo {

    public static void  main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("HOLA!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I had to make minor edits to get it to run. see suggested edit.

Answer (score 2):

The call to

```
Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logging.properties")
```

returns a url, so when calling `getFile` on that, the spaces are url-encoded, and the path becomes `/mnt/c/Users/Ludvig/Desktop/log%20test/foo/build/resources/main/logging.properties`. This is not a path that the `LogManager` can resolve for config, and so the logging is not successfully set up.

Call `file = file.replace("%20", " ")` fixes the issue.

However, it seems like a ugly hack, and I am hoping to see better solutions proposed to this issue.

I would also be very grateful for solutions that don't fail silently...